# Access to Variable Outside of Function Logic

Tags: jquery, variables, scope, global

```
   $(window).on("load resize", function () {
      if ($(window).width() < 768) {
          menuHeight = '0px';
          contactHeight = '100%';
      } else {
          menuHeight = ($('#desktop-menu').height() + 'px').toString();
          contactHeight = ($('.get-in-touch-home').outerHeight() + 'px').toString();
      }
   });
```

I want to access these two variables (menuHeight, contactHeight) outside of this function to be used elsewhere. I'm measuring the top height for a modal, but wan't it to be responsive on resize, not just load (it seems a simple If/Else would work in that case.) I might need some schooling on scope here. Thanks!!

Comment: If you haven't declared `menuHeight` and `contactHeight` somewhere, that code is falling prey to [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*. Be sure to declare your variables. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You define them outside the function. Also, since `load` happens fairly late in the page load process, you'll want to proactively initialize them, then update them in response to `load` and `resize`. That suggests you want a reusable function:

```
var menuHeight;                            // Defining...
var contactHeight;                         // ...them
grabHeights();                             // Proactive
$(window).on("load resize", grabHeights);  // And on events

function grabHeights() {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        menuHeight = '0px';
        contactHeight = '100%';
    }
    else {
        menuHeight = ($('#desktop-menu').height() + 'px').toString();
        contactHeight = ($('.get-in-touch-home').outerHeight() + 'px').toString();
    }
}
```

If your code isn't already in a scoping function, you probably want to put it in one:

```
(function() {
    var menuHeight;
    var contactHeight;
    grabHeights();
    $(window).on("load resize", grabHeights);

    function grabHeights() {
        if ($(window).width() < 768) {
            menuHeight = '0px';
            contactHeight = '100%';
        }
        else {
            menuHeight = ($('#desktop-menu').height() + 'px').toString();
            contactHeight = ($('.get-in-touch-home').outerHeight() + 'px').toString();
        }
    }
})();
```

...since globals are a Bad Thing™. :-)

You'll see people telling you to just go ahead and hook the event, then trigger it manually:

```
$("selector").on("event", function() {
    // ...
}).triger("event");
```

I'm not a fan. If you need to call a function, just call it.

Comment: Will go ahead and try these. Thank You!!

Comment: So, I want to be able to use this 'updating' variable in the code below, but it seems to only be getting the initial value.                                     
     `$("#contact-modal-1").animatedModal({
      modalTarget:'contact-modal',
      animatedIn:'slideInUp',
      animatedOut:'slideOutDown',
      overflow: 'scroll',
      position: 'fixed',
      top: menuHeight,
      animationDuration:'.7s',
      color: '#EBEBEB'
    });` Apologies for the poor formatting.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson try the getHeight() function from my code.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson: It won't just get the initial value unless you're doing that when it has the initial value. If you need to *update* that modal when the value changes, you'll need to call something from the change handler after updating the values.

Comment: Thanks all, will try these!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define them before:

```
var menuHeight = '';
var contactHeight = '';

$(window).on("load resize", function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        menuHeight = '0px';
        contactHeight = '100%';
    } else {
        menuHeight = ($('#desktop-menu').height() + 'px').toString();
        contactHeight = ($('.get-in-touch-home').outerHeight() + 'px').toString();
    }
});
```

You can use a function:

```
function scroll() {
  var menuHeight;
  var contactHeight;

  if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    menuHeight = '0px';
    contactHeight = '100%';
  } else {
    menuHeight = ($('#desktop-menu').height() + 'px').toString();
    contactHeight = ($('.get-in-touch-home').outerHeight() + 'px').toString();
  }

  getHeight(menuHeight,contactHeight)

}

function getHeight(menuHeight,contactHeight) {
  console.log(menuHeight,contactHeight)
}

$(window).scroll(scroll);
```

For global access (not recommend)

```
window.menuHeight = '';
window.contactHeight = '';
```

Comment: Not sure if I can use 'window' since this is a Node project, at least I read that here ; ).

Comment: @ChrisJohnson: The code in your question is clearly browser-based and already using `window`. :-) You may be writing the server part of it with Node, but this part is browser-based. But don't use `window.menuHeight` and such; doing so requires that they be global variables, which are a Bad Thing™.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder they are evil :-) Use global variables on last resort but most of the time you won't need it.